# multiple post function in redux saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I want to implement the feature of moving device to user created group. The functionality is when user selects the 
device, a create group button appears. Clicking on create group button opens up form for user to create the group and
when user fills the form with group name, the createGroup of saga will run which will have POST function implemented
and the url to create a group is

> /device_groups

, which i have done and is working but now that the user has created the group, the selected
device should move to that created group. How should i do that? The url for posting device to that created group is

> /device_group/groupId/add

In a nutshell, user selects devices or device and create a group button appears, user creates a group and then those selected devices should be moved to that group.

and it accepts only the list of selected device id.

```
function* createGroup(action) {
  console.log('action', action);
  const group = action.group;
  const deviceId = action.deviceId;
  if (yield call(isGroupValid, fromJS(action.group))) {
    yield fork(POST(`/device_groups`, createGroupSuccess, createGroupError, group));
  }
}

case CREATE_GROUP:
  return state
    .set('loading', true)
    .set('error', null);

case CREATE_GROUP_SUCCESS:
  const deviceGroups = fromJS(action.group, idReviver);
  return state.set('loading', false).set('error', null)
    .setIn(['deviceGroups', deviceGroups.get('id')], deviceGroups);

export function createGroup(group, deviceId) {
  return {
    type: CREATE_GROUP,
    group,
    deviceId
  };
}

export function createGroupSuccess(group) {
  return {
    type: CREATE_GROUP_SUCCESS,
    group,
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing I would do if possible is to change the group creation api endpoint to accept a list of device ids that go into that group. That way you only need to make that one api call.

If that is not possible, I would modify the saga to do something like:

```
function* createGroup(action) {
  try {
    const group = action.group;
    const deviceIds = action.deviceIds;
    if (yield call(isGroupValid, fromJS(action.group))) {
      // Create group
      const createdGroup = yield call(API.createGroup, group);
      // Add devices to new group
      yield deviceIds.map((deviceId) => call(API.addDeviceToGroup, createdGroup, deviceId));
      // Success action
      yield put(createGroupSuccess(createdGroup));
    }
  } catch (e) {
    yield put(createGroupFailed(group));
  }
}
```

Here API contains functions that return promises and do the actual rest calls.